# how to stop url access of external methods in zope2 using zope configuration

Tags: methods, external, zope

I need to do something on the filesystem, which requires unrestricted python, so I created an external method. The problem is that anyone can call that directly via URL, so I added a permission check. Even then, users with the sufficient permissions can call this via URL, which I don't want them to do. I only want them to have access indirectly from other pages (such as a page template that will pass sane parameters). Is there anyway to do this? from config file. So that even if create more external methods those also can't be called using URL.

Answer (score 0):

External methods are something *very* deprecated.
Drop them and switch to [browser views](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html#creating-and-registering-a-view). They live in the unrestricted python environment too.

Comment: Thanks Keul as this is a running project can't remove the externals methods also there are other methods too. So can you help me with external methods only.